# Do My C++ Classes Have to be a ref class in Windows 8 Metro Style Applications?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm aware that if I want to share my C++ code as a WinRT component to .Net and JavaScript code I have to declare my class as `public ref MyClass sealed`. But if I have a class I just want to use within my application does it need to be a ref class?

let's say I have a simple Building class. Could it be defined as follows

```
#pragma once
class Building
{
public:
    Building(int cap);
    ~Building(void);
    int get_capacity() {return capacity;}
private:
    int capacity;
};
```

and then used like this

```
std::shared_ptr<Building> bldg = std::make_shared<Building>(5);
```

I would still want to instantiate it as a shared_ptr using make_shared to get reference counting, but I'm just confused at what point I need to make it a ref class.

Comment: `auto bldg = std::make_shared<Building>(5);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Herb Sutter recommends](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-532T) (12 minutes in) that you only use the non-standard C++/CX at the boundaries of your program, where your C++ code has to interact with WinRT. So that would mean that classes that you only intend to use from C++ have no need to be ref classes or use anything other than ISO standard C++.